# Souls and Psychic Damage - HP in a Magic Jar?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage-types, curses, soul

Suppose you are presently under the effects of Magic Jar and are stuck inside your glassy prison. A hostile spellcaster waltzes toward you and casts a spell that does psychic damage, such as Psychic Scream or Wrathful Smite (which does not specify targeting a creature, if that matters).
What happens?
Do souls have hit points after a fashion? I would think ordinarily souls would be immune to damage, but Psychic seems like the sort of thing that would still work, especially because you're still conscious as a soul in a Magic Jar, which leads to a couple of related concerns ... Do souls have hit points? Death saves?

#### Situation

A player of mine wants to get themselves stuck in a Magic Jar to test the effects of a curse on their soul that does DoT psychic damage when they're not wearing a particular item.  Once their soul is in the jar and therefore no longer effectively wearing the protective item, though, what happens when the curse starts trying to deal damage?

I'm more looking for a general answer (especially because my players are liable to get themselves disembodied in other ways later in the campaign).  Souls may not have a stat block, but there are mechanisms by which they can be destroyed.

Comment: Are you asking for guidance on Psychic Scream/Wrathful Smite (and other psychic sources) or guidance on the curse? If the latter, we will need to know the details of the curse as it may be relevant to whether the creature is damage or the soul is damage (which is not an official mechanic in 5e).

Comment: I'm asking for psychic damage to souls in general. I provided my situation in case the possibilities were too numerous.

Answer (score 6):

The text of the Magic Jar specifies what happens when any of the *bodies* involved die, but nothing about dying souls. That suggests that the possibility of the soul dying was never even considered, so I'd say **no, your soul does not have HP, does not have a stat block and cannot take damage.**

As per the curse, that is really a separate question and probably deep in the DM's decision territory, but I would compare it with what happens when you get e.g. petrified – all diseases and poisons and such stop taking effect until you get back to your normal state. Maybe this could be handled in the same fashion (not taking DoT until you get a body again, but the curse would still stick with you = your soul).